# How to use "other" option with checkbox and text input

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I´m trying to make a text input appear when I click on the "outra", that means "other" option on the checkbox...
I want it to appear just when i click that and then it will register that thing on the database.
Does anyone know how to help me?

Code with the functions:

```
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" value="5">
      Outro
    </label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="9" class="input-field4" id="input" name="teste">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input').hide();
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    console.log(e)
        if (e.target.id == "checkboxes-4" && e.target.checked) {
            $('#input').show();
        } else {
            $('#input').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>

  <tr>
  <th>Doenças</th>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-7">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-7" value="8">
      Outra
    </label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="9" class="input-field4" id="input1" name="teste1">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Contacto em caso de emergência</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contacto_emergencia" value="<?php echo $contacto_emergencia;?>"/></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>
<p align=right>
<button type="submit" value="Alterar">Alterar</button>
<button type="cancel" onclick="window.location='http://donutsrool.pt/ficha_aluno.php';return false;">Cancelar</button>
</p>
</form>
            </div>
</div>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input1').hide();
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    console.log(e)
        if (e.target.id == "checkboxes-7" && e.target.checked) {
            $('#input1').show();
        } else {
            $('#input1').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework or anything? You would want to add a function that checks if the checkbox is checked. Judging from your tags, I'll offer a JQuery suggestion.

The JQuery to accomplish that might look like:
`$('#checkboxes-4').is(":checked")`

And then you would conditionally show your text input. So maybe:

```
if ($('#checkboxes-4').is(":checked")) {
  $('#id_of_textbox').hide();
} else {
  $('#id_of_textbox').show();
}
```

Comment: ```<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" value="5">
      Outro
    </label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="9" class="input-field4" name="teste">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <script>
  if ($('#checkboxes-4').is(":checked")) {
  $('#teste').show();
} else {
  $('#teste').hide();
}
  </script> ```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/smebdi/zwu926t1/14/

Take a look at this code example and see if that explains it a little better

Comment: I made that for other group of checkboxes, and when i open the first one, the second one closes.. do you know what do I need to do on the function to work with the two?

Comment: Your new code appears cut off. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. When you say ```$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
        if (e.target.id == "checkboxes-4" && e.target.checked)```  

You're telling the code a few things. Any time any checkbox is checked or unchecked, if its id is "checkboxes-7" and checkboxes-7 is checked, show the input. Otherwise hide it.

Comment: You could modify your on change to only look at a specific checkbox instead of all of the checkboxes. But in your original code you just stated you wanted the input to only appear if checkboxes-4 was checked and hide if it you clicked any of the others.

Comment: How can I change the code and look only on a specific checkbox?